# Pass dynamic view name and condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to display data in a view by passing the view name and where condition dynamically.

For this, I have created a function where I want to use a view and condition dynamically.

I have tried to accomplish this, but it's not working.

See few view names examples - sch.view1, sch.view2, sch.view3

```
Create function dbo.getviewdata
   (@viewname nvarchar(128), @wherecondition nvarchar(128))
return table
as
return
   select * from sys.partitions where object_id = object_id(@viewname)
```

I want to add where condition also for the same view.

Please advise me on how to do it?

The reason for choosing function, in PROD, I can only run function using `select statement`. I cannot run `procedure` in prod.

Comment: The only way you can do that is using dynamic SQL, and you can only use dynamic SQL in a stored procedure, not a function.

Comment: Problem is I cannot execute Stored procedure in PROD. Is there any round about solution?

Comment: Nope... although in my opinion generically calling a view with a dynamic where clause is totally the wrong way to go about using SQL. One should query a specific view with a specific where clause for the circumstances under which is is being used. Generic SQL is not really how its intended to be used and is not a design pattern I would encourage.

Comment: @DaleK, I agree with the Stored Procedure, but I think in Dinesh's case, he cannot call the SP, but he can call it via `select * from openrowset...` right? I think that would be the best suitable answer for him...

Comment: @Birel if you have an answer, add it as an answer :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what Dinesh's requirements are specifically, his question does not make a lot of sense to me, so I'm not sure how to dev the SP.  No offence Dinesh.

Comment: I cannot run SP in prod. But i can run select * from dbo.functionname(view)...something like this. My requirement is to pass view name dynamically and where condition along with value to get data.

Comment: It is past time for you to start asking questions of your teammates, seniors, boss for direction. What you ask is impossible and this direction seems to be a much larger [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). And developers should NEVER have access to production database - so perhaps your organization needs to find a way to provide access to production database in a different environment?

Answer (score 0):

```
  declare @view varchar(100)='xyz'
  declare @whre varchar(max)=''
  if(len(@whre)=0 or @whre is null)
  exec('create view '+@view+' as select * from sys.partitions')
  else
  exec('create view '+@view+' as select * from sys.partitions where '+@whre)
  exec('select top 10 * from '+ @view)
```

Comment: Pretty sure OP doesn't want to create the view... which for sure can't be done in a function.